# how can I change android application developed on android 2.2 platform to android 1.6?

Tags: android

A website hosts only android 1.6 platform developed applications.. What changes should I make to my project so that it runs as android 1.6 one? Would any change of minSDK from 8 to 4 suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Cristian said, as long as your app isn't using any 2.x API's that weren't available in 1.6, then it should just be as simple as setting the minimum sdk version in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using newer features than what 1.6 supports, you will just have to change the `minSdkVersion` on your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. On the other hand, if you are using specific Android 2.2 features like using `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` on your XML layouts, then you will have to rewrite those snippets of code.